# Python subprocess Popen: Why does "ls *.txt" not work?

Tags: python, subprocess, ls

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output) question.

In my case, I want to do a :

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', 'folder/*.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()
```

Now I can check on the commandline that doing a  "ls folder/*.txt" works, as the folder has many .txt files.

But in Python (2.6) I get:

*ls: cannot access * : No such file or directory*

I have tried doing:
`r'folder/\*.txt'`
`r"folder/\*.txt"`
`r'folder/\\*.txt'`
and other variations, but it seems `Popen` does not like the `*` character at all.

Is there any other way to escape `*`?

Comment: Escape it? I think what you want is to expand the "*" first and then run the ls command. Read up on "shell expansion".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`*.txt` is expanded by your shell into `file1.txt file2.txt ...` automatically. If you quote `*.txt`, it doesn't work:

```
[~] ls "*.py"                                                                  
ls: cannot access *.py: No such file or directory
[~] ls *.py                                                                    
file1.py  file2.py file3.py
```

If you want to get files that match your pattern, use `glob`:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('/etc/r*.conf')
['/etc/request-key.conf', '/etc/resolv.conf', '/etc/rc.conf']
```

Comment: Thank you. When using Popen in Python, you have to use quotes.  Please see the linked answer, or the Python documentation.

Comment: @aaa: The problem was that you weren't using a shell, which won't allow globbing. Calling `ls` with `Popen` isn't a great idea, IMO, since Python provides better tools for that.

Comment: ahhh, now I understand. Yes, you are right, glob is a much better library. See, I just learned a new thing :)

Answer (score 8):

You can pass the parameter shell to True. It will allow globbing.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('ls folder/*.txt',
                     shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I had incorrectly assumed that the args to Popen must be arrayed, as that's how all examples do it

Comment: p.communicate() is a blocking call , can we have the same behavior in a non-blocking manner ? thanks